# Ember-data nested-url adapter doesnt show request payload in request headers

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js, authorization, ember-data

Ember-data doesn't support nested API urls in models. For that we need to write our own custom adapter. I have added the [nested_url_adapter](https://github.com/rjackson/ember-data-nested-urls/blob/master/config/adapters/nested_url.es6.erb) . 
The issues that I am having right now::

1. When doing a POST request to the api "http://api.server/resource/resourceId/childResource", 
   the request payload on the request headers is not present.

2̶.̶ ̶I̶ ̶a̶m̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶e̶m̶b̶e̶r̶-̶s̶i̶m̶p̶l̶e̶-̶a̶u̶t̶h̶ ̶l̶i̶b̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶u̶t̶h̶e̶n̶t̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶a̶u̶t̶h̶o̶r̶i̶z̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶,̶ ̶w̶h̶i̶l̶e̶ ̶d̶o̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶P̶O̶S̶T̶ ̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶,̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶A̶u̶t̶h̶o̶r̶i̶z̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶.̶

I have implemented the same nested_url adapter with little modification to the type.typeKey as per my api server.

Here are the gist of the files that I have in my application: 
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/b2d11f04e881257de050)

XHR request tabs::

```
Remote Address: 127.0.1.1: 80
Request URL: http: //api.server/events/9/tickets
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Request Headersview parsed
OPTIONS / events / 9 / tickets HTTP / 1.1
Host: api.server
Connection: keep - alive
Access - Control - Request - Method: POST
Origin: http: //0.0.0.0:4300
User - Agent: Mozilla / 5.0(X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 36.0.1941.0 Safari / 537.36
Access - Control - Request - Headers: accept,
client_id
Accept: *
/*
Referer: http://0.0.0.0:4300/event/9/manage/tickets
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 24 Apr 2014 11:51:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.11-2+deb.sury.org~precise+2
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, client_id, client_secret
Access-Control-Max-Age: 0
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html*/
```

POST request ::

```
Remote Address: 127.0.1.1: 80
Request URL: http: //api.server/events/9/tickets
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 201 Created
Request Headersview source
Accept: application / json,
text / javascript,
*
/*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
client_id:[object Object]
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Host:api.server
Origin:http://0.0.0.0:4300
Referer:http://0.0.0.0:4300/event/9/manage/tickets
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:242
Content-Type:application/hal+json
Date:Thu, 24 Apr 2014 11:51:07 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Location:http://api.server/events/9/tickets/24
Server:Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.11-2+deb.sury.org~precise+2*/
```

As per [marcoow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2527893/marcoow)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267174/ember-data-nested-url-adapter-ember-simple-auth/23275058#23275058) the 2nd issue has been solved. Still the 1st issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using Ember.SimpleAuth with cross-origin requests you have to explicitly whitelist these origins to have the Authorization header added by Ember.SimpleAuth (that's a security feature to make sure your token doesn't get published all across the internet) - see here: http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-api-docs.html#Ember-SimpleAuth-setup

Comment: Accidentally added crossOriginWhitelist to OAuth2.reopen . Sorry for that.